# Sails.Js implement friendly url

Tags: sails.js

I'm new on sailjs. Do you know if it is possible to implement a friendly URL system ?

For exemple, if i want to manage products, how can i handle it in my controller by the formatted title instead of just id.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sailsjs has no built in support for this but the steps you have to take are pretty simple.

These formated strings in your urls are called slugs. A quick search on [npm](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/slug) delivers several results.

The way to handle slugs with sails is to implement [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models) (scroll down a bit to the section about the callbacks) on your product model.

Use the beforeCreate method and generate your slug into a property on your model. Inside beforeUpdate you should check if the data that you have slugged before has changed and create a new slug if needed.

Create a matching [route](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/routes). e.g /product/:slug

In your controller you just switch your where clause from the product id to the property you generated in your models beforeCreate method.

If the possibility exists that two products have the same name you should add the product id or other unique info to the slug.

happy coding. if something is unclear leave a comment